# How can i execute a php code which is stored in a database as a string

Tags: php, mysql

i have store this content as a string in my database. column name is title. i retrieve this code by loop through resultset but the php code is commented in the html code. I want that any code that is php in database it should execute. String is given bellow in curly braces:

{

"We have already seen how to embed Java expressions in JSP pages by putting them between the `<%=` and `%>` character sequences.
But it is difficult to do much programming just by putting Java expressions inside HTML.

JSP also allows you to write blocks of Java code inside the JSP.

```
<?php if(!empty($chapter['path'])){ echo "<img src='chapter_images/".$chapter['path']."'>"; } ?>
```

You do this by placing your Java code between `<%` and `%>` characters (just like expressions."

}

if i am not wrong it is possible but how it is ?
please somebody help out from this problem.

Comment: You probably are looking for `eval()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example helps you in knowing it. First while loop is to execute the code on the page. Next while loop demonstrates that I had stored the php code into the database.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("stackdb");

$result = mysql_query("select  * from demo");
$result1 = mysql_query("select  * from demo");
$d='';

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $d = $row1[0];
    eval($d);
}
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Demo application </h1>

    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
    ?>
        <p><?php echo($row[0]);?></p>
        <p><?php echo($row[1]);?></p>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help you.